# JavaScript component does not have a method named "available" when using transformrequest

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I'm learning Angular and I have a request object that is of this form:

```
var data = {
   destinationProjectId: proj.Id,
   items: $scope.selections   // this is an array
}
```

$scope.selections gives me back the actual JavaScript object back.  The endpoint expects the items array to have the Id of the selections only.  I know I could just do something like:

```
var newItems = [];
$scope.selections.forEach((obj) => {
   newItems.push(parseInt(obj.Id));
});
```

and send that with $http.  But what I'm trying to do is:

```
$http({ method: "POST", url: url, data: $scope.selections, 
transformRequest: (data, headers) => {
   var payload = [];
   var s = <any>data.items;
   s.forEach((o) => {
      payload.push(parseInt(o.Id));
   }); 
   return payload;
});
```

In the firebug console, I get:

`[Exception... "JavaScript component does not have a method named: "available"'JavaScript component does not have a method named: "available"' when calling method: [nsIInputStream::available]"  nsresult: "0x80570030 (NS_ERROR_XPC_JSOBJECT_HAS_NO_FUNCTION_NAMED)"`

What might be going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [Exception... "JavaScript component does not have a method named: "available"'JavaScript component does not have a method named: "available"' when calling method: [nsIInputStream::available]" nsresult: "0x80570030 (NS_ERROR_XPC_JSOBJECT_HAS_NO_FUNCTION_NAMED)"

This is an error in some firefox plugin. Not your code. `nsIInputStream` is an API by firefox for plugins. (ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsIInputStream)

Perhaps update your firebug or check other plugins.

Comment: Error occurs on fresh install of firefox, no extensions and in private window. Thanks for the insight though.